# Centering a range with its labels on the same level in a div

Tags: html, css, range, label

I'm trying to center a range with its labels on each side inside a div. Problem is, it isn't working.

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;">
    <label for="min1" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 15px;">0%</label>
    <input id="price" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <label for="max1" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 15px;">100%</label>
</div>
```

With the code I have right now, the first label appears on top of the range element, on the left side, and the second label also appears on the left side but under the range, as seen in the following image:

![not centered]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc6Gg.jpg)

The only thing that's centered is the range. I also tried using a form, but while the labels appear on the sides (something I want) on a full screen, when I checked the website on mobile, the labels were out of place again, just like in the picture. This is my first time experimenting with web. Thanks a lot.

Note: not sure if it's relevant to my problem but I'm using Bootstrap.

Edit: adding the CSS (from the Bootstrap file)

```
input[type=range]{display:block;width:50%}
label{display:inline-block;max-width:100%;margin-bottom:5px;font-weight:700}
```

Comment: have you tried float rigth?

Comment: I tried using it on the whole div (the others inside the same one began acting strange), then I applied it to the label max1 and the result was this http://imgur.com/a/lz3MT

Comment: here's a [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/podpsehn/) where I've pasted your code and everything looks fine to me.

Comment: Here's working fine also, probably there's some css rule that are overriding these properties. Post the whole css for us please.

Comment: I'm not sure why it looks weird for me... That div is inside another div, but it has enough space to work properly, just like in the Fiddle, and yet, it isn't. And I can't even center the elements in the container div, the only thing that gets centered is the range element...

Comment: I removed the display:block line and now the labels are where they had to be (thank you Yuri!). I'm going to try centering the whole div inside its container (the second part of my problem)

Comment: I already centered it, thanks a lot Yuri and JSmith :)

Comment: It was a pleasure to help, please upvote mine and JSmith answers here by clicking on the left arrowup if our answers helped you. Welcome to stackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#slider {
  width: 250px;
}

#label2 {
  margin-left: 188px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="label1">0%</span>
  <span id="label2">100%</span>
  <br>
  <input id="slider" type="range" value="0">
</div>
```